# .Net Design Pros/Cons: Objects Referencing Each Other Vs. Events?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

TruckStop has a List(of TruckClass) and a Method called Weigh().  TruckClass needs to call Weigh().  What are the Pros/Cons of the following two designs?  TruckClass having a reference to the TruckStopClass and calling MyTruckStopClassReference.Weigh() Vs. TruckClass raising a TruckClass.Weigh Event that is handled by TruckStopClass.

I've read that objects referencing each other won't affect the GC, but it would require the extra reference in each TruckClass.  On the other side of the coin, I've read that Event Handlers are references too and can cause issues if you don't unwire them.  A little clarity or commentary on the pros/cons/best practices/opinions on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: I presume you only have one truck stop with one or more scales and many trucks. Stick to reality where possible - the truck stop manages the scales, so your TruckStop class would have to call GetWeigh() on the Trucks. You couldn't have it the other way around because the trucks wouldn't know if there's a scale available or it's not their job to know

Comment: Truck/TruckStop is a made up example.  Not to mention a trucker could decide to first get fuel before it decided to get weighed.  I'm more concerned with Pros/Cons of Objects referencing each other vs an object raising an event in a situation where a "child class" has to trigger some method call of a "parent class".

Comment: A con would be that the child is coupled to the parent when it need not be.. they have separate responsibilities and should be treated as such. A discussion about the garbage collector is overkill at this point..

Comment: Mr. Whitehead, are you saying the TruckStop reference in the Truck object is a Con due to coupling or both situations?

Comment: Not related to the question. I once had this kind of situation. Each object would have a reference to the list when adding them. Got into weird problems when trying to put the same object into two different list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the two approaches are concerned I'd be more inclined to lean towards the two classes being individual and not tied together by events/handlers. In this theoretical case I would have the weigh function be inside a module or a shared function of the truck stop class and have it take the truck as a parameter.

If you were going to go the event route then having one class handle an event raised in a seperate class isn't a very preferable way of doing things. And in my personal opinion if I ever did that I would feel very dirty because it would cause the two classes to be so tightly coupled that it would at the very least feel like you were butchering the OOP design.

Something I have done in the past to consolidate form initialization when dealing with a program that could call the same forms from multiple locations is have all the possible places that can launch the form raise an event to a common container, whether its a base form or a container class or something along those lines, and then on that parent form/class/container I handle each event coming from all the children. The good thing about this is you can have all the events handled by one sub procedure(or function, however you want to define it) that calls the form initializer and if you ever need to change how a form is created and shown its all in one place.

This example isn't strictly relevant to your example but if you change your example a bit and say that two classes can both cause some vehicle to be weighed then centralizing the access point to the truckstop's weigh function would make managing the project just that much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As a follow up, would that mean that the Form/Button relationship is also a butchering of OOP design?  Button is part of the Form's Controls Property, raises events like Click, yet is a separate class.

Comment: @NoAlias: I've always thought of any contol and the parent form as a special case but when you step back and look at them as stand alone classes then it does fit the pattern. I would say the line is drawn when the class raising the event _depends_ on the class that is handling the event. So in the case of buttons and forms they would pass the OOP test because the button doesn't care if anything is listening for the click it will fire it whenever it is clicked no matter what. So following that raising the event in "truck" wouldn't be bad if it doesn't rely on something listening for it.

Answer (score -1):

My solution would be to include both the TruckClass and the Weigh() method in the TruckStop class.  Something like:

```
Class TruckStop
    Class Truck
        (private attributes)
        (public properties)
    End Class

    Public Shared Function Weigh(truck) as Weight
        (code)
    End Function
End Class
```

and reference like this:

```
weight = thisTruckStop.weigh(thisTruckStop.Truck(truckNum))
```